# Write to a Hudi table in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-hudi

The Hudi documentation only shows how to write to a hudi table from Pyspark CLI, which is ran with these parameters:

```
pyspark \
--packages org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.2-bundle_2.12:0.11.1 \
--conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' \
--conf 'spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog' \
--conf 'spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension'
```

(taken from https://hudi.apache.org/docs/quick-start-guide)

This is my code that should write some data to a table, but it's a part of a bigger Python script, so it doesn't have these command line parameters and it causes an error (Failed to find data source: hudi):

```
 hudi_options = {
        'hoodie.table.name': tableName,
        'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'asset_id, exception_configuration_id, channel_name, event_ts',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'partitionpath',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.table.name': tableName,
        'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'ts',
        'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 2,
        'hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism': 2
    }
    path = '/table/'
    df.write.format("hudi").options(**hudi_options).mode("overwrite").save(path)
```

I tried creating a SparkSession with the same configuration as above:

```
    session = SparkSession.builder.appName("hudi-test")\
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")\
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog")\
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension")\
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.2-bundle_2.12:0.11.1").getOrCreate()
```

It doesn't change the outcome because it's not used in the dataframe operation that inserts data into Hudi. What's the proper way to do the insert operation?

Comment: are you sure you are using spark 3.2 with scala 2.12?